# ¿Se pueden guardar las direcciones de los punteros en un archivo csv para después asignar esas direcciones a otros punteros? (C++)

Tags: c++, array, archivo, punteros

Sé que suena raro pero quería saber si existe la posibilidad en C++ de escribir las direcciones que guarda un arreglo dinámico en un archivo de tal forma que puedas leer el archivo y usar las direcciones guardadas con otros punteros. ¿Cómo sería la forma de meter y sacar las direcciones del archivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Existe la posibilidad en C++ de escribir las direcciones que guarda un arreglo dinámico en un archivo?

Por supuesto:

```
int *arreglo = new int[10] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

if (std::ofstream salida{"salida.txt"})
{
    for (int indice = 0; indice != 10; ++indice)
    {
        salida << &arreglo[indice] << '\n';
    }
}
```

> ¿Cómo sería la forma de meter y sacar las direcciones del archivo?

Para guardar datos lo hemos visto en el código anterior, para leerlos sería como el código siguiente:

```
if (std::ifstream datos{"salida.txt"})
{
    for (int indice = 0; indice != 10; ++indice)
    {
        int valor;
        datos >> std::hex >> valor;
        std::cout << std::hex << valor << " = " << *reinterpret_cast<int *>(valor) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Cuando envías un puntero a un flujo de datos de salida el puntero se muestra en hexadecimal, es por eso que al leerlo debemos usar `std::hex` si queremos su valor. Hemos usado un entero (`int`) y no un puntero a entero (`int *`) para leer el contenido del archivo porque no existe sobrecarga para leer desde flujo de datos a puntero... pero podemos crear dicha sobrecarga:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, int *&v)
{
    int valor;
    i >> std::hex >> valor;
    v = reinterpret_cast<int *>(valor);
    return i;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVHZbsIwEHyOv2KaShDAraB3SZofoaiyEkMtBTtyDEVC@fZ0nYPSPley5NlrdnY3K8ubrBB62zTXSmfFPpdIlKmclWKXsh/fZnCxyuXLpepMjEwprXDGpmn0O6A4lHaYjg4TdmKBxwdRGBsTRpqizf6UR4@HwAFvsJJSpS2tdB@ZqFzSsqRRmzOhJArsrYaKWc2YD@6E0tG5yVRYK7eFISotv7yG1WK@xglzjgXHHcc9xwPHI8cTxzPHC8cr6phR@QbdEKafFpUoVC5OYfffuqML6wkLqFWwMRaRb6h0rjJJ7ebxgK/esCBrNutsqmhLgo4GSYJRr3LVZay9b/yuxzRfUDN6F2rUoCanRVf/JqZd1rD5IGjJL49Bcn33zOydV9e6PQiJPfRgenb9UZ7LQjq5WqMf0u@2v9qcrtY03w)</kbd>.

---

#### ¿No te parece raro que no exista la sobrecarga para leer punteros?

El código que he puesto en el compilador online funciona porque los punteros usados pertenecen a la misma ejecución del programa, si guardamos las direcciones de memoria del programa y acto seguido lo cerramos, esas direcciones de memoria dejarán de ser válidas en la siguiente ejecución.

Para entenderlo, tenemos que imaginar que la memoria es como un Hotel, cuando pides una habitación te asignarán una de las habitaciones disponibles en ese momento.

[image]

Mientras estés registrado en el Hotel puedes hacer uso de la habitación pero en el momento en que hagas el checkout pierdes los derechos sobre la habitación que usabas. Si vuelves al al Hotel en otro momento es probable que no te asignen la misma habitación y lógicamente no tendrás derecho alguno sobre la habitación que usaste la vez anterior.

Por lo tanto, volvamos a tus preguntas:

> ¿Existe la posibilidad en C++ de escribir las direcciones que guarda un arreglo dinámico en un archivo de tal forma que puedas leer el archivo y usar las direcciones guardadas con otros punteros?

Si, se puede hacer. No, no se debe hacer. No diseñes tu código confiando en esa funcionalidad.